Async function failing in typescript - unable to locate or fix error
I am trying to run my server using npm run dev and getting an error as follows:
> pern-chat-app@1.0.0 dev
> NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm' nodemon --watch backend/src --exec ts-node backend/src/index.ts

(node:1924) ExperimentalWarning: `--experimental-loader` may be removed in the future; instead use `register()`:
--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("ts-node/esm", pathToFileURL("./"));'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[nodemon] 3.1.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): backend/src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node backend/src/index.ts`
(node:1941) ExperimentalWarning: `--experimental-loader` may be removed in the future; instead use `register()`:
--import 'data:text/javascript,import { register } from "node:module"; import { pathToFileURL } from "node:url"; register("ts-node/esm", pathToFileURL("./"));'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "[object Object]".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

This error does not seem to give much detail for now but these are the two files involved, one is the auth.routes.ts file and one is the auth.controller.ts file:
auth.route.ts file:
import express from 'express';
import { signup, login, logout } from '../controllers/auth.controller.js';


const authRoute = express.Router();

//remember - these are prefixed with http://localhost:5001/api/auth/
authRoute.post("/signup", signup);
authRoute.post("/login", login);
authRoute.post("/logout", logout);



export default authRoute;

auth.controller.ts file:

import { Request, Response } from "express";
import prisma from "../db/prisma.js";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import generateToken from "../utils/generateToken.js";

interface SignupRequestBody {
    fullName: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    confirmPassword: string;
    gender: string;
}

export const signup = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response | void> => {
    try {
        const { fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender } = req.body

        if (!fullName || !username || !password || !confirmPassword || !gender) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Please make sure to fill out all fields." });
        }
        
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Passwords don't match." });
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { username } });
        
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: "Username already taken." })
        }

        const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);

        //https://avatar-placeholder.iran.liara.run/document
        const boyProfilePic = `https://avatar.iran.liara.run/public/boy?username=${username}`;
        const girlProfilePic = `https://avatar.iran.liara.run/public/girl?username=${username}`;

        const newUser = await prisma.user.create({ 
            data: {
                fullName,
                username,
                password: hashedPassword,
                gender,
                profilePic: gender === "male" ? boyProfilePic : girlProfilePic,
            }
         });

         if (newUser) {
            generateToken(newUser.id, res)

            res.status(201).json({
                id: newUser.id,
                fullName: newUser.fullName,
                username: newUser.username,
                profilePic: newUser.profilePic,
            })
         } else {
            res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid user data." });
         }

    } catch (error: unknown) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            // Safely access stack and message properties
            console.error("Error in signup controller", error.stack || error.message);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error." });
        } else {
            // Handle the case where error is not an instance of Error
            console.error("Unexpected error", error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error." });
        }
    }
};

export const login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {}

export const logout = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {}

Now the error relates to the signup function in auth.routes.ts, here:
authRoute.post("/signup", signup);

When I hover over it, it shows:
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<Response | void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>) => Promise<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(164, 5): The last overload is declared here.
(alias) const signup: (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<Response | void>
import signup

This is my first time using typescript and I'm trying to follow a youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vL24eiwAG_g
I've tried chatgpt also to try help diagnose. The only thing I managed to do was to put //@ts-ignore just above the routes and then the server ran fine so it is a typescript issue as far as I can tell.
Any help welcome here, thanks so much!

You have three spots where you do res.status(n)... without awaiting. I'd try awaiting those. You also might need to await generateToken.

@TrevorDixon hasn't made a difference. When I put the await in it just gives me a message saying:
'await' has no effect on the type of this expression
